# Any way to load CSON files via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cson

I'm wondering if there's some way I can use something like `$.getJSON()` to load a CSON file from a server. I don't even know where to start. I've been Googling around but haven't found anything solid. Node.js has a CSON library it can use:

```
data = CSON.parseFileSync('test.cson')
```

Surely there's something I can use client-side.

Comment: Fetch it as plain text and parse it with a cson parsing library?

Comment: I can't seem to find a CSON parsing lib for client-side JS (or a jQuery plugin).